# Iterating with numpy with different indexes

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

Say I have a for loop using range as shown below. Is there a good way to eliminate the for loop and use numpy arrays only?

```
y =[146, 96, 59, 133, 192, 127, 79, 186, 272, 155, 98, 219]

At=3
Bt=2
Aindex=[]
Bindex=[]
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    A =At
    B =Bt

    At =y[i] / y[i] + 5 * (A + B)
    Aindex.append(At)
    Bt =(At - A) + y[i+1] * B
    Bindex.append(Bt)
```

I would use something like

```
c=len(y)-1
Aindex=y[:c]/y[:c]+5* (A + B)
```

But A and B updates in the loop. I also do not know how to vectorize  y[i+1] in the Bt equation

Comment: You should use enumerate(y) instead of range(len(y)-1)

Comment: @Leifingson I know I just made the example on the fly. I would actually use np.arange to vectorize it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked something similar in [Iterating over a numpy array with enumerate like function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20808313), except there `A` and `B` did not change.

Strictly speaking you can't vectorize this case, because of that change in `Bt`.  This an iterative problem, where the `i+1` term depends on the `i` term.  Most of the `numpy` vector operations operate (effectively) on all terms at once.

Could you rework the problem so it makes use of `cumsum` and/or `cumprod`?  Those are builtin methods that step through a vector (or axis of an array), calculating a cumulative sum or product.  `numpy's` generalization of this is `ufunc.accumulate`.
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html

In the meantime, I'd suggest making more use of arrays

```
y = np.array(y)
At = np.zeros(y.shape)
Bt = np.zeros(y.shape)
At[0] = 3
Bt[0] = 2 
for i in range(len(y)-1):
    A, B = At[i],Bt[i]
    At[i+1] =y[i] / y[i] + 5 * (A + B)
    Bt[i+1] =(At[i+1] - A) + y[i+1] * B
```

`numpy` uses an `nditer` to step through several array (including an output one) together.   http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html   Though I suspect it is more useful when working on multidimensional arrays.  For your 1d arrays it is probably overkill.  Still if speed becomes essential, you could work through this documentation, and implement the problem in `cython`.