# Python Numpy iteration improvements for Exponential smoothing (working code) for Github pull request

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I put a [pull request](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/pull/1287) in for Statsmodel exponential smoothing on Github and would like to know if there is a good way to improve this loop. So far I have working code and want to work out the kinks. It handles a variation of Exponential smoothing models.

Is there a good way to make this loop more efficient?

```
   for i in range(ylen):
        s = sdata[i]
        b = bdata[i]
        #handles multiplicative seasons
        if season == 'multiplicative':
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] / cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * s * (b**damp)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] / s) + (1 - gamma) * (b ** damp)
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] / sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
        #handles additive models
            else:
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] / cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * (s + damp * b)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] - s) + (1 - gamma) * damp * b
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] / sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
        else:
            if trend == 'multiplicative':
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] - cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * s * (b**damp)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] / s) + (1 - gamma) * (b ** damp)
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] - sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
            #handles additive models
            else:
                sdata[i + 1] = alpha * (y[i + 2] - cdata[i]) + (1 - alpha) * (s + damp * b)
                bdata[i + 1] = gamma * (sdata[i + 1] - s) + (1 - gamma) * damp * b
                cdata[i + cycle] = delta * (y[i + 2] - sdata[i + 1]) + (1 - delta) * cdata[i]
```

I also posted on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/38563/help-improve-my-my-python-code-for-exponential-smoothing-sumitted-to-statsmodel) if you want the to test the full code. Please help suggest improvements. I have been programming only for several months so any help would be appreciated. Documentation for the code is also on the pull request at Github with sources.

Comment: You calculate `(1 - alpha)`, `(1 - gamma)` and `(1 - delta)` 3N times. They are constants so calculate them once before the loop. `b**damp` is sometimes calculated twice per loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, most of the code in each of the 4 cases is identical. It's actually difficult to pick out which parts are different. That's a recipe for hard-to-find bugs. Pull the identical parts out of the conditionals; the if/else should only handle the part that actually changes.

Second, you're working with NumPy. You shouldn't be looping at all; you should find a way to use vectorized operations to perform your task. The [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802020005/http://wiki.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-4c1d53fe504adc97baf27b65513b4b97586a4fc5) shows some of the basics of vectorized operations. Vectorized code is shorter and far more efficient than code that uses explicit loops.

Comment: I am looking for a vectorize way to do this but the closest thing I found on stack shows the problem can't be resolved because 2 values update depend on the i term see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809850/iterating-with-numpy-with-different-indexes